# Calculate how many times a static number fits into another number

Tags: php, math, numbers, calculator, surface

For a surface calculation I am searching for the following solution.

I have a size of the surface like 60m², for this square I have 2 kind of
materials sizes. Material size of 2m² and 4m². The challenge for me now is
to calculate the needed materials efficiently as possible and keep a rest
of the material to the minimum.

So, filling a surface of 60m² with most as possible with 4m² materials and fill it up with 2m2 to keep material to the minimum.

Comment: No sense without width & height datas. Else : 60/4 = 15 ! You need 15 blocks of 4m2...

Comment: The answer to both the title question and your numbers example is: **you divide and round down**. If the two numbers you want to fit in there are not multiples of one another, then things become a bit more tricky, but that's not what you're asking.

Comment: Lets say the surface is 13m2 .. I know I need 3x4m2 and 1xm2 to be efficient with materials. But than, the translation to a php calculation..

Comment: If i understand you question right I think you should use MOD,
times2 = surface % num2;
times1 = surface % num1;
minimumwaste = times2<time1?times2:times1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. With this method, you can use any number and any size of materials.

Store your materials into an array. Loop through on that array, make the calculations, and store the "rest" in another variable. If at the end there will be some rest, then add 1 more from the last item.

```
$materials = array(2,4,8);
$surface = 63;
rsort($materials);
$rest = $surface;
$isFinished = false;
$data = array();
foreach ($materials as $material) {
    $result = $rest / $material;
    if ($result >= 1) {
        $data[$material] = floor($result);
        $rest -= $material * floor($result);
    }
}

if ($rest > 0) {
    $data[end($materials)]++;
}
echo "For a " . $surface . " you need the following materials: <br />";
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    echo "Material " . $key . " * " . $val ."<br />";
}
```

Output is:

```
For a 63 you need the following materials:
Material 8 * 7
Material 4 * 1
Material 2 * 2
```

Comment: Seems to be coming really close. I just wondering about the surface calculation in meter per meter (m2 is the unit). When I do a calculation on 30 m2 surface, the result is 7x4 (m2 material) and 1x2(m2 material), that would a bit too much of materials :)

Comment: 7*4 = 28, 1*2 = 2, so 28+2 = 30. What is the problem? :)

Comment: we have 30m2. 1x 4m2 is already 16m2 so 7x16m2 would be a bit too much if I see this right?

Comment: What do you mean "1x 4m2 is already 16m2"??? 1x4m2 is 4m2 not 16m2. Do you mean, 4m2 = 16m?

Comment: Anyway, the surface is in m2 and tha materials are too.

Comment: sorry, I meant 4m2 is 16m yes :)

Comment: But the surface is in m2 too isn't it?

Comment: You are totally right. I see now I did the mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using PHP
This will be a start to find the material with minimum rest.

```
function getMinRest($surface, $num1, $num2){
  $rest1 = $surface % $num1;
  $rest2 = $surface % $num2;
  return $rest2 <= $rest1 ? $num2:$num1;
}
```